# Python NameError: name is not defined in bankAccount Example

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

so here is my code:

```
class BankAccount:
    def __init__(self, FirstName, LastName, AccNum, Balance, CreationYear, CreationMonth, CreationDay):
        self.FirstName = FirstName
        self.LirstName = LirstName
        self.AccNum = AccNum
        self.Balance = Balance
        self.CreationYear = CreationYear
        self.CreationMonth = CreationMonth
        self.CreationDay = CreationDay

    def AddAccount(self):
        self.FirstName = input("First Name: ")
        self.LastName = input("Last Name: ")
        self.AccNum = input("Account Number: ")
        self.Balance = input("Balance: ")
        self.CreationYear = input("Creatin Year: ")
        self.CreationMonth = input("Creation Month: ")
        self.CreationDay = input("Creation Day: ")
        return self.FirstName , self.LastName , self.AccNum , self.Balance , self.CreationYear , self.CreationMonth , self. CreationDay


    def Deposit(self):
        amount = input("How much do you want to Deposit? ")
        self.Balance = str(float(amount) + float(self.Balance))
        print("Balance: ", self.Balance)
        return self.Balance

    def Withdrawl(self):
        amount = input("How much do you want to withdrawl? ")
        if (float(amount) > float(self.Balance)):
            print("Insufficent Balance.")
        else:
            self.Balance = str(float(self.Balance) - float(amount))
            print("Balance: ", self.Balance)
        return self.Balance


x = BankAccount(FirstName, LastName, AccNum, Balance, CreationYear, CreationMonth, CreationDay)
x.AddAccount()
```

and this is the error im encountering

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dark\Desktop\New folder (5)\bank.py", line 38, in <module>
    x = BankAccount(FirstName, LastName, AccNum, Balance, CreationYear, CreationMonth, CreationDay)
NameError: name 'FirstName' is not defined
```

Comment: You need to pass a value in FirstName pos. Eg - `x = BankAccount('Rob', 'Roy', '123', '100', '2016', 'April', '10')`

Comment: Did you declare `FirstName`?

Comment: Classes should probably not use interactive `input()` directly. A better design would separate the functionality of the class itself from any user-facing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class `BankAccount` should not be used to collect user data for its creation; you should probably extract `AddAccount` from the class, and use it a a factory function to build the class:

Maybe something like this:

```
class BankAccount:
    def __init__(self, FirstName, LastName, AccNum, Balance, CreationYear, CreationMonth, CreationDay):
        self.FirstName = FirstName
        self.LastName = LastName
        self.AccNum = AccNum
        self.Balance = Balance
        self.CreationYear = CreationYear
        self.CreationMonth = CreationMonth
        self.CreationDay = CreationDay

    def Deposit(self):
        amount = input("How much do you want to Deposit? ")
        self.Balance = str(float(amount) + float(self.Balance))
        print("Balance: ", self.Balance)
        return self.Balance

    def Withdrawl(self):
        amount = input("How much do you want to withdrawl? ")
        if (float(amount) > float(self.Balance)):
            print("Insufficent Balance.")
        else:
            self.Balance = str(float(self.Balance) - float(amount))
            print("Balance: ", self.Balance)
        return self.Balance


def AddAccount():
    """asks input data for the creation of a bank account,
    returns the newly created bank account
    """ 
    FirstName = input("First Name: ")
    LastName = input("Last Name: ")
    AccNum = input("Account Number: ")
    Balance = input("Balance: ")
    CreationYear = input("Creatin Year: ")
    CreationMonth = input("Creation Month: ")
    CreationDay = input("Creation Day: ")
    return BankAccount(FirstName , LastName , AccNum , Balance , CreationYear , CreationMonth , CreationDay)


x = AddAccount()
```

Alternatively, you could initialize the attributes to `None`, or `zero`, and have the class request user input; However, having a `class BankAccount` handling user input may not be the best possible design...

```
class BankAccount:
    def __init__(self):
        self.FirstName = None
        self.LastName = None
        self.AccNum = None
        self.Balance = 0
        self.CreationYear = None
        self.CreationMonth = None
        self.CreationDay = None

    def AddAccount(self):
        self.FirstName = input("First Name: ")
        self.LastName = input("Last Name: ")
        self.AccNum = input("Account Number: ")
        self.Balance = input("Balance: ")
        self.CreationYear = input("Creatin Year: ")
        self.CreationMonth = input("Creation Month: ")
        self.CreationDay = input("Creation Day: ")

    def Deposit(self):
        amount = input("How much do you want to Deposit? ")
        self.Balance = str(float(amount) + float(self.Balance))
        print("Balance: ", self.Balance)
        return self.Balance

    def Withdrawl(self):
        amount = input("How much do you want to withdrawl? ")
        if (float(amount) > float(self.Balance)):
            print("Insufficent Balance.")
        else:
            self.Balance = str(float(self.Balance) - float(amount))
            print("Balance: ", self.Balance)
        return self.Balance


x = BankAccount()
x.AddAccount()
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to define the variables you pass to the class constructor.

You might want to use 1 of 3 options:

1) Define your variables before you use them e.g.

```
FirstName = "Jhon"
LastName = "Doe"
... #define rest of variables
x = BankAccount(FirstName, LastName, AccNum, Balance, CreationYear, CreationMonth, CreationDay)
```

2) Call the class constructors with literals e.g.

```py
x = BankAccount("Jhon", "Doe", "MyAccount", 200, 2019, 6, 2)
```

3) Define your variables directly inside `__init__` e.g.

```py
class BankAccount:
    def __init__(self):
        self.FirstName = input("First Name: ")
        self.LastName = input("Last Name: ")
        self.AccNum = input("Account Number: ")
        self.Balance = input("Balance: ")
        self.CreationYear = input("Creatin Year: ")
        self.CreationMonth = input("Creation Month: ")
        self.CreationDay = input("Creation Day: ")
    #rest of code
```

Comment: But if i use input inside __init__ how can i call it?

Comment: @thepreacher `input` will get automatically called when you call `__init__`. so when you define a new Bankaccount object, it will ask the user to input his details